# separate density plots with same colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot that has hundreds of background densities and a single observed density.  I'd like each of the background densities to have the same appearance (color, linetype, etc.) and the observed density will be the only one that is different.

Is there a simple way to "group" the background data so that each density is plotted as a separate line without dividing by color/shape/fill/etc...?

Here is the closest I've come, but I'd like the density plots to all have the same appearance:

`df <- replicate(100,{rnorm(20,0)}) %>% cbind(rnorm(20,1)) %>% melt
ggplot(df) + 
    geom_density(aes(x=value, color=factor(Var2)),alpha=.1) +
    geom_density(data=df[df$Var2==101,], aes(x=value),color="black")`

[image]

Comment: yes, move the color aestetic like you did already in the sencond `geom_density` and use `group` aestetic.

Comment: Thank you.  Amazingly simple.  Didn't know about the 'group' aesthetic.